# How to disable installation of stuff on my operating system drive?

Tags: windows-7, windows

Hey I've recently bought a new computer with a 120GB SSD (solely for Windows 7) and a 2TB WD mechanic drive.

Now obviously 120GB isn't that much - but some installers keep on insisting placing files on C: even though I set the main install directories on D: (the 2TB HD).

Is it possible to somehow prevent stuff from being added to my op system drive and just install them all on my 2nd drive?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not easily. The files they install on the C: drive are often shared libraries that have to go into specific windows folders to work correctly, even if you're installing the application-specific executables onto a different partition.

Comment: Pretty much this -- if the installer doesn't allow for it, you probably can't force it.  The easiest thing you can do is symlink/junction particular folders to a different volume after the fact.

Comment: They shouldn't be putting THAT much there anyway.  120GB is more than enough for Windows AND all your software applications (unless you play a ton of games AND leave them all installed simultaneously)

Comment: Yeah I feared this.. I run several development environments and they always take up so much space on the main drive. And always trash gets left behind even if you uninstall games/programs.

Answer (score 0):

You can play around with the access rights to the Program Files and Program Files (x86) directories on the C: drive to remove all but one user's rights to write to those directories. Then, only ever log in as that user (or use that user account's credentials in a UAC prompt) when you simply must go in and make a change to those folders.

However, Darth's right on the whole; a lot of programs are architected with the assumption that they'll be installed on the C drive, and/or they require assemblies to be placed in the GAC (%windir%\assembly) or System (%windir%\system32) folders. There are nearly always ways to avoid this, but many programmers/software architects/installer writers make the incorrect assumption that you'll do it their way, and not your own.